# "retrieved ancestor invalid" message during synchronization

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

We have been running a private ethereum network for a couple of months.

Today we tried to add a new node to the network.  When the node was 
synchronizing, (after 3-4 hours) it stopped with the following message :

5a0e number=847268 hash=0000...0000 allowance=847268
WARN [03-23|15:11:45] Synchronization failed dropping peer
5a0e err="retrieved ancestor invalid"

We tried it again by starting from scratch (deleting all retrieved chain) 
and the same problem appeared again at the same number=847268.

I will appreciate your help on resolving this issue.

Comment: you figure this out?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem but solved it in the following way.

1. Go to your chaindata directory like "/home/user/.ethereum/testnet/geth/chaindata"
2. Delete some of the recent ldb files and .log file. ( I've deleted 10 recent files.)

Comment: Got `Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: missing block number for head header hash` after doing this.